# How Spring treats BeanPostProcessors differently from regular beans?

Tags: java, spring

In order to register our custom [`BeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) in an application we need to define it as a bean in our application context. For sure, Spring treats those bean differently from regular ones(first priority instantiation).

Where I can see the code which checks whether or not the class of a bean is [`BeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) and then processes the bean differently?

I thought that this is check need to be done before any regular bean will be created so I tried to search in [`XmlBeanDefinitionReader`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/XmlBeanDefinitionReader.html) and
[`AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.html) but I didn't find what I want.